# Finding limits of integration in convolution

Tags: limits, integration, convolution

I am struggling to fully get how to choose proper limits of integration when calculating convolutions.  Right now I am stuck on a problem where I have to show that when taking the Fourier transform of the convolution of two rectangular functions, the result equals the square sinc function.

So, I have defined:

$f(t) = 1$ for $-1 < t < 1$

$f(t) = 0$ otherwise

By taking the convolution of this function with itself, I have set up:

$$f \ast f (t)= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) f(t - \tau) d \tau$$

And this is where I struggle to find the correct limits of integration.  I know that when I solve this, it is an easy matter to set up a Fourier transform, and since this transform is integrated with respect to $t$, it is easy to see that the limits of integration then will be $-1$ and $1$.  But how do I determine the limits here when we integrate with respect to $\tau$?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will never find sinc here.

Comment: I know that I will not find sinc^2 by just performing the convolution.  I have to also take the FT.  Or is it some other reason for that?  Anyways, my main question here is really about how to choose proper limits of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since $f(\tau)=0$ outside of $[-1,1]$, we have
$$
f\ast f(t)=\int_{-1}^1f(t-\tau)d\tau.
$$

Now change the variable by $u=t-\tau$:
$$
f\ast f(t)=\int_{t-1}^{t+1}f(u)du.
$$

If $t+1\leq -1$ (ie $t \leq -2$), or if $t-1\geq 1$ (ie $t\geq 2$), then $(-1,1)\cap (t-1,t+1)=\emptyset$ so $f\ast f(t)=0$.

Let us consider the case $-2<t<2$ now.

First, if $-2<t\leq 0$, then $1+t\leq -1$ and $[t-1,t+1]\cap [-1,1]=[-1,t+1]$ so
$$
f\ast f(t)=\int_{-1}^{t+1}1du=2+t.
$$

Second, if $0\leq t<2$ then $1-t\geq 1$ and $[t-1,t+1]\cap [-1,1]=[t-1,1]$ so
$$
f\ast f(t)=\int_{t-1}^{1}1du=2-t.
$$

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, you're welcome!

Comment: Hi, if I have $-2 \le t \le 0$, I add +1 to both sides to get $-1 \le t+1 \le 1$. Why do you say then that $1+t \le -1$?